# activedirectory finduser method issue in Nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory

I'm using activedirectory npm package with Nodejs v16.18.1, I`m using the following code to first authenticate, then finduser to get its details:

***Plz can you help here!***

```
async  authUserActiveDirectory(usernameAD: string, pass: string) {
    const config = {
        url: 'ldap://192.168.136.136',
        baseDN: 'DC=octopusadlocal,DC=com',
        username: usernameAD+'@octopusadlocal.com',
        password: pass,
    };
      
    const ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);    
    const userName = usernameAD+'@octopusadlocal.com';
    ad.authenticate(userName, pass, function(err, auth) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error authenticating user:', userName);
        }
        if (auth) {
            console.log('Usernames', userName, 'authenticated successfully');               
            const sAMAccountName = userName;
            ad.findUser(sAMAccountName, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {                
                    console.log(err)
                }
                if(!user) {
                    console.log('no user exists')
                } else {
                    console.log(user)
                }
           })  
        } else {
            console.log('User', userName, 'not authenticated');
        }
    });
}
```

***The Output:***

> using ad.finduser of activedirectory package, it generates the following issue:
> Usernames oct1@octopusadlocal.com authenticated successfully

> /validation/node_modules/activedirectory/lib/activedirectory.js:416
> delete result.controls; // Remove the controls array returned as part of the SearchEntry
> ^
> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at CorkedEmitter.onSearchEntry (/validation/node_modules/activedirectory/lib/activedirectory.js:416:5)
> at CorkedEmitter.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at CorkedEmitter.emit (/validation/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/corked_emitter.js:44:33)
> at sendResult (/validation/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1233:22)
> at messageCallback (/validation/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1253:14)
> at Parser.onMessage (/validation/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:919:14)
> at Parser.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Parser.write (/validation/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/parser.js:135:8)
> at Socket.onData (/validation/node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:875:22)
> at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)

Comment: I`m not sure why nobody is responding to my question; but I`m  now not surprised so much why AI and ChatGPT is taking all this reach out and loud marketing. We put question here, it takes days before any coming comment or feedback; while there in AI, the feedback is instantenous even though 50% is correct....So plz Guys let`s keep these communities specially stackoverflow alive!!

Answer (score 0):

No issues using ldapjs 2.3.3. looks like it's incompatible with ldapjs 3.0.0.;

Here i found the solution [link](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/issues/246)